# get all the nested folders names (no path) from a path

Tags: c#, .net

I am a little confused how to get the nested folders name from a given path. There could be no folders to many folders.

here is what I've done. I've also tried to substring but then I get 1 result returned and its the same for the entire file.

```
foreach (string fL in GetDirectories(targetDirectory))
            {
                foreach (string fN in ProcessDirectory(fL))
                {
                    string[] subType = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);

                    myDocs.Add(new Documents
                    {
                        Id = "1",
                        Directory = directory,
                        Type = type,
                        FilePath = filePath,
                        FileName = fN,
                        Description = description,
                        SubType = subType
                    });
                }
            }
```

The output that I get looks like:

```
{
    "Id": "1",
    "Directory": "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee",
    "Type": "QA",
    "FilePath": "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/New Text Document.txt",
    "FileName": "New Text Document.txt",
    "Description": "New Text Document",
    "SubType": [
        "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee\\New folder",
        "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee\\New folder - Copy",
        "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee\\New folder - Copy (2)",
        "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee\\New folder - Copy (3)",
        "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee\\New folder - Copy (4)",
        "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee\\New folder - Copy (5)",
        "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee\\New folder - Copy (6)",
        "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee\\New folder - Copy (7)",
        "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee\\New folder - Copy (8)",
        "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee\\New folder - Copy (9)"
    ]
}
```

Desired result:

```
{
    "Id": "1",
    "Directory": "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee",
    "Type": "QA",
    "FilePath": "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/New Text Document.txt",
    "FileName": "New Text Document.txt",
    "Description": "New Text Document",
    "SubType": [
        "New folder",
        "New folder - Copy",
        "New folder - Copy (2)",
        "New folder - Copy (3)",
        "New folder - Copy (4)",
        "New folder - Copy (5)",
        "New folder - Copy (6)",
        "New folder - Copy (7)",
        "New folder - Copy (8)",
        "New folder - Copy (9)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is this on Windows? I have never seen `Directory.GetDirectory()` return paths with a forward slash.

Comment: @SimonC Unfortunately, it doesn't. I need it to be in an array because I'll have a folder with many folders nested inside and I need to get those nested folders names and store it in an array. I've tried it but maybe I'm implementing it wrong :(

Comment: @TanveerBadar correct it is windows, I replaced the "\\" with a "/".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.8) to get the name of a directory from the full path. Yes, it's called Get**FileName**, but it literally just [takes everything after the last slash](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,1007). (it doesn't actually look at the file system)

If you're ok using Linq, you can do this:

```
string[] subType = Directory.GetDirectories(directory)
                            .Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();
```

Comment: Just need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file. Linq's [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) is really just the same as a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you mention if you're okay with using Linq?

Comment: I don't think anyone would object to using it here. But sometimes, in more complicated statements, it can be difficult to decipher what it's actually doing, as opposed to a `foreach` loop.